# Basic Color class for both Delphi and Lazarus

Tags: classes, delphi, object-pascal

### Intro

If you want to know, then about 10+ years ago, I started a journey on the (*best* in my country) color picker for WinXP, later Win7. Since now it is hardly compatible with Win10 and HiDPI (work in progress), and in no way compilable in Linux using Lazarus, it would take quite an effort to create a decent desktop color picker with zoom and everything on Linux. But first things first - in this question I would like to start with basic color class, i.e. class capable of holding single color, and providing easy access to each color component, except for hue sat lum, which I'm not able to program, and am not asking you to point me to any direction. At the bottom I attached this code to existing color picker for windows just to show what it is doing. I want to start from scratch and maybe re-invent the wheel just to practice my brain.

---

### TBasicColor class

```delphi
unit basic_color;

interface

uses
    Graphics;

type
    TBasicColor = class
    strict private
        FColorRef: TColor;
    protected
        function GetColorRef: Integer;
        function GetRed: Byte;
        function GetGreen: Byte;
        function GetBlue: Byte;
        function GetCyan: Byte;
        function GetMagenta: Byte;
        function GetYellow: Byte;
    public
        constructor Create; reintroduce;
        constructor CreateRandom;
        constructor CreateColorUsingRGB(const ARed, AGreen, ABlue: Byte);
        constructor CreateColorUsingCMY(const ACyan, AMagenta, AYellow: Byte);
        property ColorRef: Integer read GetColorRef;
        property Red: Byte read GetRed;
        property Green: Byte read GetGreen;
        property Blue: Byte read GetBlue;
        property Cyan: Byte read GetCyan;
        property Magenta: Byte read GetMagenta;
        property Yellow: Byte read GetYellow;
    end;

implementation

constructor TBasicColor.Create;
begin
    inherited Create;
    // implicitly initialize to white color
    CreateColorUsingRGB(255, 255, 255);
end;

constructor TBasicColor.CreateRandom;
begin
    inherited Create;
    FColorRef := Random($FFFFFF + 1);
end;

constructor TBasicColor.CreateColorUsingRGB(const ARed, AGreen, ABlue: Byte);
begin
    inherited Create;
    FColorRef := ARed or (AGreen shl 8) or (ABlue shl 16);
end;

constructor TBasicColor.CreateColorUsingCMY(const ACyan, AMagenta, AYellow: Byte);
begin
    CreateColorUsingRGB(255 - ACyan, 255 - AMagenta, 255 - AYellow);
end;

function TBasicColor.GetColorRef: Integer;
begin
    Result := Integer(FColorRef);
end;

function TBasicColor.GetRed: Byte;
begin
    Result := Byte(FColorRef);
end;

function TBasicColor.GetGreen: Byte;
begin
    Result := Byte(FColorRef shr 8);
end;

function TBasicColor.GetBlue: Byte;
begin
    Result := Byte(FColorRef shr 16);
end;

function TBasicColor.GetCyan: Byte;
begin
    Result := 255 - GetRed;
end;

function TBasicColor.GetMagenta: Byte;
begin
    Result := 255 - GetGreen;
end;

function TBasicColor.GetYellow: Byte;
begin
    Result := 255 - GetBlue;
end;

end.
```

---

### Screenshot from Windows

[image: Screenshot from Windows]

---

Whatever you answer, I value all input. Thank you.

Comment: A bit late, but here it goes ;-) I wouldn't make this a class but an advanced record a.ka. a record with methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Self-review

---

### `Randomize` missing

Since I use `Random` to generate pseudo-random color, it is, I lightly remember, a must to call `Randomize` once program or unit in this case is being created; [more information](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Randomize).

```
// ...

initialization
    Randomize;

end.
```

---

### Get... Red, Green, Blue, Cyan, Magenta, Yellow

These seem to operate as expected.

---

### `constructor`s

The biggest error I already see I have made is the `constructor` *thing*. The problem is I did not write one for direct `TColor` assignment. It could be re-written for instance like this in the `interface`:

```
type
    TBasicColor = class
    // ...
    public
        // default direct TColor assignment constructor
        constructor Create(const AColor: TColor); overload;
        // reintroduce is hiding TObject constructor
        constructor Create; reintroduce; overload;
        // create using RGB values
        constructor CreateRGB(const ARed, AGreen, ABlue: Byte);
        // create using CMY values
        constructor CreateCMY(const ACyan, AMagenta, AYellow: Byte);
        // create pseudo-random color constructor
        constructor CreateRandom;
    // ...
```

Plus, like this in the `implementation`:

```
constructor TBasicColor.Create(const AColor: TColor);
begin
    // in here it is just plain assignment
    inherited Create;
    FColorRef := AColor;
end;

constructor TBasicColor.Create;
begin
    // in case anyone just calls Create() we assign white color
    Create($FFFFFF);
end;

constructor TBasicColor.CreateRGB(const ARed, AGreen, ABlue: Byte);
begin
    Create(ARed or (AGreen shl 8) or (ABlue shl 16));
end;

constructor TBasicColor.CreateCMY(const ACyan, AMagenta, AYellow: Byte);
begin
    CreateRGB(255 - ACyan, 255 - AMagenta, 255 - AYellow);
end;

constructor TBasicColor.CreateRandom;
begin
    Create(Random($FFFFFF + 1));
end;
```

As you can see, all, in the end, are calling the *default* `constructor`, which I see as much better implementation.

---

### `overload` keyword

Note on `overload` keyword, I originally did not need it in Lazarus, but Delphi requires it.

---

### Comments

By the way, I should really use more comments, they will prove useful one day, once I read it after years.

---

### Why read-only ColorRef?

On second thought, I see no reason for the ColorRef not being able to change at runtime, I find it hard to see what reason I had before, but no matter, it should stay a private member with properties to safely read and write, also the typecast might be *wrong*, cannot confirm or disprove at this point, best to typecast when necessary in-place.

For example with private method `Assign`:

```
procedure TBasicColor.Assign(const ColorRef: TColor);
begin
    if (ColorRef < 0) or (ColorRef > $FFFFFF)
        then raise ERangeError.Create('ERangeError in TBasicColor class.' + sLineBreak +
                                      'It supports only subset of TColor range.' + sLineBreak +
                                      'Valid range is <0; $FFFFFF>.')
        else FColorRef := ColorRef;
end;
```

which can in turn be used in the SetColorRef *setter*:

```
procedure TBasicColor.SetColorRef(const ColorRef: TColor);
begin
    Assign(ColorRef);
end;
```

---

### `ARed` change to `Red`, etc.

I believe it's a habit or style point, but anyway.

I removed, and am no longer a fan of an `A` prefixing, changed to this:

```
constructor TBasicColor.CreateRGB(const Red, Green, Blue: Byte);
constructor TBasicColor.CreateCMY(const Cyan, Magenta, Yellow: Byte);
```

---

### Modified code

After a few other adjustments, I will name only the use of *setters* in all color components, this unit could be re-written finally to this state:

```
unit basic_color;

interface

uses
    Graphics, SysUtils;

type
    TBasicColor = class
    strict private
        FColorRef: TColor;
    private
        // TColor assignment with range check <0; $FFFFFF>
        procedure Assign(const ColorRef: TColor);
        // independent function needed (Delphi/Lazarus; Windows/Linux)
        function RGBToColor(const Red, Green, Blue: Byte): TColor;
    protected
        function GetColorRef: TColor;
        procedure SetColorRef(const ColorRef: TColor);
        function GetRed: Byte;
        procedure SetRed(const NewRed: Byte);
        function GetGreen: Byte;
        procedure SetGreen(const NewGreen: Byte);
        function GetBlue: Byte;
        procedure SetBlue(const NewBlue: Byte);
        function GetCyan: Byte;
        procedure SetCyan(const NewCyan: Byte);
        function GetMagenta: Byte;
        procedure SetMagenta(const NewMagenta: Byte);
        function GetYellow: Byte;
        procedure SetYellow(const NewYellow: Byte);
    public
        // default direct TColor assignment
        constructor Create(const ColorRef: TColor); overload;
        // reintroduce is hiding TObject default constructor
        constructor Create; reintroduce; overload;
        // create color using RGB values
        constructor CreateRGB(const Red, Green, Blue: Byte);
        // create color using CMY values
        constructor CreateCMY(const Cyan, Magenta, Yellow: Byte);
        // create pseudo-random color
        constructor CreateRandom;
        property ColorRef: TColor read GetColorRef write SetColorRef;
        property Red: Byte read GetRed write SetRed;
        property Green: Byte read GetGreen write SetGreen;
        property Blue: Byte read GetBlue write SetBlue;
        property Cyan: Byte read GetCyan write SetCyan;
        property Magenta: Byte read GetMagenta write SetMagenta;
        property Yellow: Byte read GetYellow write SetYellow;
    end;

implementation

procedure TBasicColor.Assign(const ColorRef: TColor);
begin
    if (ColorRef < 0) or (ColorRef > $FFFFFF)
        then raise ERangeError.Create('ERangeError in TBasicColor class.' + sLineBreak +
                                      'It supports only subset of TColor range.' + sLineBreak +
                                      'Valid TBasicColor range is <0; $FFFFFF>.')
        else FColorRef := ColorRef;
end;

function TBasicColor.RGBToColor(const Red, Green, Blue: Byte): TColor;
begin
    Result := Red or (Green shl 8) or (Blue shl 16);
end;

constructor TBasicColor.Create(const ColorRef: TColor);
begin
    // in here it is just plain assignment
    inherited Create;
    Assign(ColorRef);
end;

constructor TBasicColor.Create;
begin
    // in case anyone just calls Create() we assign white color
    Create($FFFFFF);
end;

constructor TBasicColor.CreateRGB(const Red, Green, Blue: Byte);
begin
    Create(RGBToColor(Red, Green, Blue));
end;

constructor TBasicColor.CreateCMY(const Cyan, Magenta, Yellow: Byte);
begin
    CreateRGB(255 - Cyan, 255 - Magenta, 255 - Yellow);
end;

constructor TBasicColor.CreateRandom;
begin
    Create(Random($FFFFFF + 1));
end;

function TBasicColor.GetColorRef: TColor;
begin
    Result := FColorRef;
end;

procedure TBasicColor.SetColorRef(const ColorRef: TColor);
begin
    Assign(ColorRef);
end;

function TBasicColor.GetRed: Byte;
begin
    Result := Byte(FColorRef);
end;

procedure TBasicColor.SetRed(const NewRed: Byte);
begin
    Assign(RGBToColor(NewRed, GetGreen, GetBlue));
end;

function TBasicColor.GetGreen: Byte;
begin
    Result := Byte(FColorRef shr 8);
end;

procedure TBasicColor.SetGreen(const NewGreen: Byte);
begin
    Assign(RGBToColor(GetRed, NewGreen, GetBlue));
end;

function TBasicColor.GetBlue: Byte;
begin
    Result := Byte(FColorRef shr 16);
end;

procedure TBasicColor.SetBlue(const NewBlue: Byte);
begin
    Assign(RGBToColor(GetRed, GetGreen, NewBlue));
end;

function TBasicColor.GetCyan: Byte;
begin
    Result := 255 - GetRed;
end;

procedure TBasicColor.SetCyan(const NewCyan: Byte);
begin
    SetRed(255 - NewCyan);
end;

function TBasicColor.GetMagenta: Byte;
begin
    Result := 255 - GetGreen;
end;

procedure TBasicColor.SetMagenta(const NewMagenta: Byte);
begin
    SetGreen(255 - NewMagenta);
end;

function TBasicColor.GetYellow: Byte;
begin
    Result := 255 - GetBlue;
end;

procedure TBasicColor.SetYellow(const NewYellow: Byte);
begin
    SetBlue(255 - NewYellow);
end;

initialization
    Randomize;

end.
```